# Powermail doesn't send mail

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I have installed powermail extension 4.4 on typo3 v7.6 project, the test mail is sending good, but when I fill the form on frontend and click submit, no e-mail is delivered/arrives.

- I configured the form in backend with name, e-mail, and subject for both receiver and sender.
- I have used different e-mail addresses too.
- I have also tried to disable the spamshield from typoscript : spamshield._enable = 0.
- I have added a defaultEmailAdress in the installtool config : [MAIL][defaultMailFromAddress] .

Does anybody have another idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that, the problem was that i have used an different email adress in the plugin different from the adress in the smtp setting of installtool, this is was wrong, i have to use the same adress.

Answer (score 3):

Whats in your LocalConfiguration.php ?

```
    'MAIL' => [
    'transport' => 'sendmail',
    'transport_sendmail_command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ',
```

should mostly work fine. But maybe you need to change transport to smtp or something else?

What really works good for me is the setup with [Mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog), to try Emails in Development.